# Get only two values from 4 specified columns and merge valid values into 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

df:

```
index      a          b          c           d
-
0          1          2          NaN         NaN
1          2          NaN        3           NaN
2          5          NaN        6           NaN
3          1          NaN        NaN         5
```

df expect:

```
index      one        two
-
0          1          2         
1          2          3     
2          5          6        
3          1          5
```

Above output example is self-explanatory. Basically, I just need to shift the two values from columns [a, b, c, d] except NaN into another set of two columns ["one", "two"]

Comment: There are always 2 non NaNs values per rows?

Comment: Lots of NaNs, I have hundreds of columns with NaNs, but they only have 2 valid values amongst all hundreds columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use back filling missing values and select first 2 columns:

```
df = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, :2].astype(int)
df.columns = ["one", "two"]
print (df)
       one  two
index          
0        1    2
1        2    3
2        5    6
3        1    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `combine_first` + `drop`:

```
df['two']=df.pop('b').combine_first(df.pop('c')).combine_first(df.pop('d'))
df=df.drop(['b','c','d'],1)
df.columns=['index','one','two']
```

Or `fillna`:

```
df['two']=df.pop('b').fillna(df.pop('c')).fillna(df.pop('d'))
df=df.drop(['b','c','d'],1)
df.columns=['index','one','two']
```

Both cases:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   index  one  two
0      0    1  2.0
1      1    2  3.0
2      2    5  6.0
3      3    1  5.0
```

If want output like @jezrael's, add a: (both cases all okay)

```
df=df.set_index('index')
```

And then:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
       one  two
index          
0        1  2.0
1        2  3.0
2        5  6.0
3        1  5.0
```